# How to parse a JSON variable inside html document with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I got the following html document:

**document.html**

```
<head>
  <!-- head stuff -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- lot of html -->

  <script>
    yt.setConfig({
    'VIDEO_ID': null,
    'IS_UNAVAILABLE_PAGE': true  <!-- I want to get true from here -->
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

and I want to get **true** from here using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
'IS_UNAVAILABLE_PAGE': true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack is intended to parse HTML, not JS.

Since JS is not HTML, it is allowed for you to parse one simple javascript string with a Regex:

```
new Regex("'IS_UNAVAILABLE_PAGE': (?<value>true|false)");
```

However, if you want to find out the real in-memory value of a variable in run-time, than neither HtmlAgilityPack nor Regex could help you.